# Copy files from ftp server using php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to come up with a scehduled copy code with php.
I dont have problem copying from shared folder via eg //xxx.xx.xxx/folder/filename.csv ( remote computer ). I have some files located at a ftp server. How can I do the same?

Appreciate any help

```
$file = 'ftp://xx.xx.xxx.xx/Log/123.csv';
$newfile = 'spc/ems_files/123.csv';
if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
    echo "Copy success!";
} else {
    echo "Copy failed.";
}
```

---

Additional info

Bask on the feed I used php ftp function to connect to the ftp using below code
based it said failed to connect. I can connect it with a FTP software like filezilla without much issue. What is wrong ?

```
$ftp_server = "10.76.170.123"; 
$ftp = ftp_connect("10.76.170.123");
if (!$ftp) die('could not connect.');

// login
$r = ftp_login($ftp, "anonymous", "");
if (!$r) die('could not login.');

// enter passive mode
$r = ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
if (!$r) die('could not enable passive mode.');

// get listing
$r = ftp_rawlist($ftp, "Log");
var_dump($r);
```

Comment: sorry, your question is unclear to me. What is it doing now and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to copy csv files from a few places to the webserver. I can copy remotely from shared folder but not from a ftp server

Comment: and where exactly is the problem?

Comment: my guess: permission denied for ftp, because you might need a username/passoword.

Comment: eg : one from shared folder via //123.45.123 -- this is running fine but from f t p://122.111.222 its not working

Comment: Connecting to a domain under the `ftp://` protocol *usually* requires a username and a password... And a different port, usually port 21. PHP `copy()` works great on `http://` protocol, which is on port 80. You should look for [`ftp_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php)

Comment: I added more info after trying to use php ftp to connect but failed. However I can connect to it using filezilla easily. Please see the update question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.default ftp connection used email address as password 
I used this to connect to the ftp successfully

$r = ftp_login($ftp, "anonymous", "anonymous@domain.com");

So I chose to use php FTP function to do the downloading task

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're doing should be possible, as long as the FTP server supports passive mode and you are using the correct credentials. I would double-check the path to the file, on the FTP server, is correct too.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php

Here are some other solutions you could try ...

- SFTP using phpseclib - http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html
- FTP Functions in PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php